# A Maze of Colors

Tags: visual, computer-puzzle, mazes

I'm back and I have another maze for you. This time it'll be an image with squares of color.

[image: Maze]

**Start at the yellow block and end at the red block, both of which are at the bottom border of the maze. You have to move with one-square steps. You'll have to find out the rest.**

There's a pattern that allows you to determine if something is a wall or not. (not counting for the outside black border)

Here are some of the colors you can step on:

> Dark green [image: color example], desaturated purple [image: color example]

Here are some of the colors you can't step on:

> The stack of colors near start with the top color being [image: first color] and the bottom color being [image: last color]. The full stack of colors looks like the below image. 
> [image: Full row of colors]

Comment: Are there any rules?

Comment: Start at the yellow block and end at the red block, both of which are at the bottom border of the maze. You'll have to find out the rest.

Comment: This looks like the piet programming language...

Comment: Hey Peanut, I edited in the start and end instructions to the question itself, since they seem to be an integral part of the puzzle. Hope that's okay.

Comment: @DanRussell Okay.

Comment: @CaelanO It isn't related to any esoteric programming languages.

Comment: If this is anything like the puzzle in Undertale, red tiles are impassible!

Comment: Go straight from yellow to red? There isn't any rule against it is there?

Comment: I'm pretty sure any "digital conversion" similar to your other maze would work (i.e. "black" becomes 000000 and would therefore form a direct path). I think the puzzle would become a bit better with *a little* instruction on what is allowed and what isn't. Otherwise I agree with @Areeb: No rule means taht I can just directly connect... As I'm sure you've had a nice idea in mind, ammending the puzzle a bit seems like a good idea.

Comment: @BmyGuest Dark green hex code is 006400 so we would have a vertical wall of zeros between the start and the end of the maze. (0=wall because black is 000000)

Comment: Peanut, I think if you want to have people "work" on this, you need to at least give a general direction of the puzzle. Is the colour image to be "converted" to something which gives a regular maze, i.e. walls and paths? Are we to find out a reason why we can step on some colours, but not on others? Are the "moves" continuous horizontal/vertical steps or arbitrary, but linked by colour? etc. Right now, the parameter space of possibilities is just too big as to make this into a proper puzzle. You not even provide what one must NOT do, so "I jump from the yell to the red) is a valid solution!

Comment: Peanut, could you tell if we are supposted to "step" through the maze with regular steps (i.e. horizontal/vertical steps of one square), or is this part of the puzzle as well?

Comment: You have to move with one-square steps.

Comment: Hmm, I ll give it some more thought then, but right now (18hrs flight) my brain is too soggy...

Comment: Is "Desaturated purple" (145,92,137) a red herring? I don't seem to find that colour in the image itself. (The closest being 122,70,171)

Comment: @BmyGuest, no, it is not. The color may be a little off. (the desaturated purple I'm talking about is the one right above the finish going in an upside-down `J` shape)

Comment: So the exact color values are of no importance then , or did you just make a mistake in the hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is based on the newly given hints.

> Based on the "forbidden steps" hint, essentially the only way from yellow is straight upwards (as all tiles to the right are outside wall and to the left are forbidden.) until one reaches the dark green.

From there on...

> There is a direct path to the exit only using dark green and desaturated purple tiles. Both are specified as "allowed" so that's the way to go...

Why?

> I do not have the faintest idea, but the hints give only that choice...

According to the OP:

> The only thing that counts is if a pixel's hex-value is even or odd. So, what is needed is to either look at the last digit of the full hex-colour-value, or just the "blue" channel

which gives you the following image:

> [image: Solution]

Comment: This is the correct way, but explain how you determine what is the wall and what isn't. What is different between the disallowed tiles and the allowed ones?

Comment: The maximum number of adjacent tiles of different colour is 3? (Not counting border tiles)

Comment: @Peanut Do you think it is time to "solve" this puzzle as you intended it? (Either in a comment here, as a self-answer, or as a comunity wiki?)

Comment: I simply forgot to mark this as correct. Here's your rep.

Comment: @Peanut: Can you explain *why* this was the solution? Why are those colors specifically allowed?

Comment: @Peanut thanks, but actually I m more interested in what your intention for the solution was than in the rep. I have the feeling I m still missing something.

Comment: @Deusovi The hex code must the even (or the last digit)

Comment: @Peanut: ...How were we supposed to guess that? We can't exactly read minds.

Comment: @Deusovi There are 4+ colors that you can step on and not step on. They all follow the same pattern.

Comment: @Peanut I think the criticism here is, that the *condition* is kind of arbitrary and can not be *logically* derived at. So, without "Your" statement, there is not really a single "true" solution. Multiple solutions become equally valid. Also it seems that your solution allows more than one path, which makes it even harder to guess what you meant.

Comment: @BmyGuest The two paths leading to the exit line was accidental. Only the top path was supposed to work.

Answer (score 10):

A kind of **arbitrary** solution to a - so far - *arbitrary* puzzle:

> - I *assume* one square represents one "pixel" or one "field".
>  - I *assume* one may not step on BLACK and DARK GREEN squares.
>  - I *assume* the move has to be like the chess knights.
>  - I *assume* we have to start on the Yellow and end on the red dot.

With all these **assumptions**, and because there is no rule-set given, this would be my solution:

> [image]

---

I should add, that while the answer above is a bit of a joke, I **did** take the puzzle serious and was/am searching for some more obvious relationship. This is what I have thought so far:

> - The puzzle should need the **color** information somehow, otherwise it is all just a huge, red-herring. (Any only *red* is relevant.)
> - If BLACK squares would be allowed to be moved on, this would be trivial, so I rule that out.
> - If all NON-BLACK sqaures can be moved on, this would be trivial, so I rule that out.
> - If we are allowed to move on the DARK-GREEN squares, we could basically move nearly everywhere, so I rule that out.
> - Any CONTINUOUS move has to step either on BLACK or DARK GREEN, so I rule them out.
> - Trying to utilize the PEANUT pixels: The rect of pixels is 23x4 or 28x10 depending if you just cut the text or the whole white area. Unfortunately the colour-dots form a grid of 14x8 (or 14x9), so I can see no relationship.
> - I followed the idea of "teleporting" fields, assuming pixels of *same* color are linked. Unfortunately, the very pixels next to the yellow entrance (both the pale yellew and the light green) are of a colour nowwhere else to be found (exactly), so that fails...

---

It was suggested that the colours in the pixels could be shown in their RGB hex representation with considering the zeros as wall. Doing this with the image, assuming one square is the "natural" resolution of the image, gives:

[image]

which does not lead to a useful maze.

---

Another observation is, that - starting with the yellow pixel on the right - neighbouring pixels always seem to have *one* channel (red/green/blue) with value zero. Unfortunately, this breaks down when coming to the left side, as the red pixel does not neighbour to a colour with one channel being zero.

Also: The pale purple which touches the red pixel is *not* of the same colour (exactly) as the one given as "allowed" hint...

Comment: (On mobile) What is the resolution?  Is each "pixel" actually a pixel or is it finer than that?  Possibly breaking it down into rgb will show "borders" that are linked by a common value.

Comment: @LeppyR64 Its a 256 x 256 PNG file with "sharp" edges between the squares, but nice idea.

Comment: @BmyGuest, I resized it so it wouldn't appear as a tiny square. It was originally smaller than that (probably 64 by 64 pixels)